# The variable is not detected in R studio

Tags: r, variables, math

I have a problem with my code:

```
k=1.815264e-06  
b=1/k
alpha = 0.05
p=90
pstar=1/(1+p)
pstar1=pstar
sxinvers=function(x)
{-b*log(x)}
if (alpha < pstar){
  retensiCTE = sxinvers(pstar)
} else if (alpha == pstar){
  retensiCTE >= sxinvers(pstar)
}
retensiCTE
```

When I run this code, I get an

> Error: object 'retensiCTE' not found

Why does this happen? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your alpha is not smaller than pstar and not equal so I add an else statement with `NA` to complete it. In R the last line of the function is automatically returned so I add retensiCTE at the end of each statement like this:

```r
k=1.815264e-06  
b=1/k
alpha = 0.05
p=90
pstar=1/(1+p)
pstar1=pstar
sxinvers=function(x) {-b*log(x)}

if (alpha < pstar) {
  retensiCTE = sxinvers(pstar)
  retensiCTE
} else if (alpha == pstar){
  retensiCTE >= sxinvers(pstar)
  retensiCTE
} else {NA}
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>